# Reopen dialog remains open after confirming question reopening

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, popup

This is a minor bug reporting. In reopen votes queue if I want to reopen a question, I get a confirmation dialog. I confirm the reopening, but the dialog does not disappear (examples for SO and politics):

[image: SO reopen dialog]

[image: Politics reopen dialog]

Tried in Chrome and Brave.

Clicking outside will close it, so this is a minor bug IMO.

Comment: I actually clicked it again, assuming I misclicked. That leads to an error message stating you already voted to re-open.

Comment: @rene I would say it should be the other way around. Adam already updated the status here, thus he's working on this question. So the other question should be a dupe of this one to be linked to the one with the implementation status.

Comment: @Tom Adam has been long enough around to see what has happened and will update / edit / close / answer how he sees fit. I have no worries.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I'm on it. Thanks for the report - I evidently missed the other ones :)

Comment: @AdamLear Can you please set the new tag status-completed (or remove status-review)? I can't do that myself. Also thank you for fixing this bug.

Comment: @Tom No problem. Done!